# Kleene Algebra for star-free regular expressions

Tags: regular-language, algebra, regular-expressions, first-order-logic

TLDR: Is there a notion of Kleene Algebra for star-free regular expressions?

**Kleene Algebras** are algebraic structures that are equivalent to regular expressions. A Kleene Algebra is an idempotent semiring (non-commutative multiplication) with an extra unary operation $*$ that satisfies that following equations:
\begin{align}
&1+x\cdot x^* = x^* \\ &1+x^*\cdot x = x^* \\ &z+xy\le y \implies x^*\cdot z\le y \\ &z+yx\le y \implies z\cdot x^*\le y
\end{align}
where $x\le y$ means there exists $z$ such that $x+z=y$. Equivalence with regular expressions formally means, given regular expressions $r_1$ and $r_2$, $\mathcal{L}(r_1)=\mathcal{L}(r_2)$ iff we can prove $r_1=r_2$ using the axioms of Kleene Algebra.

**Star-free regular expressions** are regular expressions without the Kleene star but with the ability to take complements i.e. $$r_1,r_2::= \emptyset\mid a,b,c\in A\mid r_1\cup r_2\mid r_1\cap r_2\mid r_1\cdot r_2\mid (r_1)^c$$ where $A$ is the set of alphabets. Observe that complementation restores some Kleene star powers but not all: $A^*=(\emptyset)^c$ while $(aa)^*$ has no star-free form.

I was wondering how to tweak Kleene Algebra so that we capture exactly star-free expressions. While coming up with equation templates for the complementation operation the challenge is to get an equation for $(r_1\cdot r_2)^c$ because the rest of the interleaving of operations is taken care of by De Morgan's laws. Also, since Kleene Algebras do not explicitly talk about the alphabet set, I guess $a^c$ should be considered a normal form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be interested in **bounded synchronization delay expressions**.
See [1] for details on these expressions.
To sum up, they are equivalent to star-free expressions, but instead of using complement, they restrict the use of the Kleene star to certain languages: the *prefix codes with bounded synchronization delay*.

This way, you can have your characterization: $L(r_1)=L(r_2)$ iff we can prove $r_1=r_2$ using the axioms of Kleene Algebra, the only difference being that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are more constrained on the use of Kleene star, and only represent star-free languages.

On the other hand, axiomatization of regular expressions with complement has been done in [2], so after careful verification, you could possibly use this to axiomatize star-free expressions directly.

[1] *Diekert, V.; Kufleitner, M.*, [**Bounded synchronization delay in omega-rational expressions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30642-6_10), Hirsch, Edward A. (ed.) et al., Computer science – theory and applications. 7th international computer science symposium in Russia, CSR 2012.

[2] 
*Salomaa, A.; Tixier, V.*, [**Two complete axiom systems for the extended language of regular expressions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TC.1968.227424), IEEE Trans. Comput. 17, 700-701 (1968). [ZBL0174.29001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0174.29001).